# Derivatives of Latin *mulier* in French

Tags: historical-linguistics, latin, french, romance-languages, cognates

It is well known that the derivatives of Latin *mulier* and *fēmina* competed in Romance languages as the main word for `woman'. For instance, the former remained as Spanish *mujer* and Portuguese *mulher* (though S *hembra*, P *fêmea* do remain). French language, however, has, to my knowledge, only *femme*.

The question is: does any descendant of Latin *mulier* remain in French language and if not, what would the gistorical derivative form look like if it survived?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [*Trésor de la langue française*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A9sor_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise) has most the answer to your question in the [etymology section for *femme*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/femme):

> From Classical Latin *femina* “female”, then “woman, wife” which competed against the Latin words *mulier* “woman” which no longer survives in French (contrast with Italian *moglie*, Spanish *mujer*) except in the archaic form *moillier* “wife, woman” (which disappears from texts in the 14th century; 2 occurrences in the 15th and 16th centuries), and *uxor* “wife” which gave the very rare *oissour* “wife” (which disappears from texts in the first half of the 13th century; a few occurrences remain in the 13th and 14th centuries in epic retellings).

So, no, it didn't survive (nor did any word based on this root that I can think of or find in a word list). The Middle French form would be *moillier*, which might have evolved to **mouiller* or **mouille* (parallel to *moiller* → [*mouiller*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mouiller)”) or possibly to something simpler if it had been a common word (possibly via variants such as *muiller* or *molier* which could have led to **molie* or **mole*).

Oddly, there is a rare modern French word which has the same root, through a different path: [*moukère* or *mouquère*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mouk%C3%A8re), which means a woman, from the Algerian Arabic word *moukera* which was a borrowing from the Spanish *mujer*.